# combining javascript object property value and display

Tags: javascript

Hi I am having difficulty in traversing in javascript object. How can I get scheme_name & NAV from both and store it in variable like "You have 2 schemes linked to your account. scheme_name1 NAV value is "" scheme_name2 NAV value is "" and so forth. Please explain it to me thanx

```
  let data = [{
  "CustomerID": 12345,
  "NAV": "95.24059718",
  "cost_of_purchase": 799900,
  "folio_number": 10007060,
  "id": 1,
  "mutual_fund_house": "AXIS MUTUAL FUND",
  "no_of_units": 15000,
  "option": "GROWTH",
  "plan": "REGULAR",
  "resource_uri": "/api/v1/folio/1/",
  "scheme_name": "AXIS LONG TERM EQUITY",
  "value_of_units": "1428608.9580"
}, {
  "CustomerID": 12345,
  "NAV": "1053.31517400",
  "cost_of_purchase": 1500000,
  "folio_number": 5540000567,
  "id": 2,
  "mutual_fund_house": "SBI Mutual Fund",
  "no_of_units": 2750,
  "option": "DIVIDEND",
  "plan": "DIRECT",
  "resource_uri": "/api/v1/folio/2/",
  "scheme_name": "SBI Magnum Multicap Fund",
  "value_of_units": "2896616.7270"
}]
```

Comment: `data.forEach(item => console.log(\`Schema ${item.scheme_name} value is ${item.NAV}\`));`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What array functions have you researched and tried?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Don't just give an answer to a question like this. What does Sumit learn from your answer except this specific answer in this specific instance? He needs to do some research.

Comment: Your data object is an array of Objects. You can use forEach() --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach to accomplish your task. Also your question doesn't meet SOF standards.

Comment: @wlh what he will learn or not is up to him. He can search over what I have suggested and learn a lot, or just copy-paste it in his code, as much of *developers* do. If he wants to copy-paste he will anyway, with or without any help, it is not my fault.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It's all good, we differ in our philosophies as it comes to Stack Overflow. Cheers.

Comment: @wlh no problem buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you try to map that object to another object.

First, try to read and understand array methods, you can check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

And for map method you can check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

And as a specific answer you can do:

```
const mappedData = data.map(function(item) {
    return {
        scheme_name: item.scheme_name,
        NAV: item.NAV
    };
});
```

This will return you an array of a simplified version of yours.

After that, you can convert it to a string like:

```
let solution = `You have ${mappedData.length} schemes linked to your account. `;
mappedData.forEach(function(mapped) {
    solution += mapped.scheme_name + ' is ' + mapped.NAV + ' '
});
```

Note: I showed map method for giving an insight about what you can do, normally you don't need to simplify, you can directly use for each version.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an array of `data` so firstly you need to iterate through that array.

Pick which properties you want to keep per record, and save them to a `results` array.

Once you have the results you can iterate through them and print out your individual records.

```js
let data = [{"CustomerID":12345,"NAV":"95.24059718","cost_of_purchase":799900,"folio_number":10007060,"id":1,"mutual_fund_house":"AXIS MUTUAL FUND","no_of_units":15000,"option":"GROWTH","plan":"REGULAR","resource_uri":"/api/v1/folio/1/","scheme_name":"AXIS LONG TERM EQUITY","value_of_units":"1428608.9580"},{"CustomerID":12345,"NAV":"1053.31517400","cost_of_purchase":1500000,"folio_number":5540000567,"id":2,"mutual_fund_house":"SBI Mutual Fund","no_of_units":2750,"option":"DIVIDEND","plan":"DIRECT","resource_uri":"/api/v1/folio/2/","scheme_name":"SBI Magnum Multicap Fund","value_of_units":"2896616.7270"}]

let results = []
data.forEach(datum => {
  results.push({
    scheme_name: datum.scheme_name,
    nav: datum.NAV,
  })
})

console.log(`You've got ${results.length} items in your account.`)
results.forEach(result => {
  console.log(`${result.scheme_name} - NAV value is: ${result.nav}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine each one of your objects (in this case you have provided two (2)) as an associative array inside of an array. Meaning that rather than reference it by it's index position, you can reference it by it's key.

This means to access  object 1, you would have to write data[0]. But if you alerted this, this would simply tell you that data[0] is an object. Which is is.

To access an actual value in that array, you would then have to provide the key, which you can do by providing a number, or in your case perhaps more easily, it's associated key, which is "scheme_name".

See the following :

```js
let data = [{
  "CustomerID": 12345,
  "NAV": "95.24059718",
  "cost_of_purchase": 799900,
  "folio_number": 10007060,
  "id": 1,
  "mutual_fund_house": "AXIS MUTUAL FUND",
  "no_of_units": 15000,
  "option": "GROWTH",
  "plan": "REGULAR",
  "resource_uri": "/api/v1/folio/1/",
  "scheme_name": "AXIS LONG TERM EQUITY",
  "value_of_units": "1428608.9580"
}, {
  "CustomerID": 12345,
  "NAV": "1053.31517400",
  "cost_of_purchase": 1500000,
  "folio_number": 5540000567,
  "id": 2,
  "mutual_fund_house": "SBI Mutual Fund",
  "no_of_units": 2750,
  "option": "DIVIDEND",
  "plan": "DIRECT",
  "resource_uri": "/api/v1/folio/2/",
  "scheme_name": "SBI Magnum Multicap Fund",
  "value_of_units": "2896616.7270"
}]

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  alert(data[i]["scheme_name"]);
}
```

So quite simply, for i = 0, with i being less than the number of associative arrays in your array named data, alert the value on that indexed array, by the associated key.

Answer (score -1):

I created sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/4npw5e6g/3/) for you. You need to iterate over each object in your main object and store all information outside.

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.scheme_name);
});
```